# Largest sum of compatible triples

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

A triple $(a,b,c)$ of distinct integers is called *compatible* if at least one of them, say $b$ has the property that either $n\mid b$ or $b\mid n,$ for each $n\in\{a,c\}.$

Let $X$ be the set of all compatible triples of integers in the interval $[1,2002]$ and, for each $x=(a,b,c)\in X,$ let $s_x:=a+b+c.$ $\hspace{1pt}$ Find:

$\bullet$ the value of $\hspace{1pt}$ $\sigma:=\max\{s_x:x\in X\};$

$\bullet$ all $x\in X$ for which $s_x=\sigma.$

Sorry for my ignorance, but, how should I approach this problem?

Comment: 1.  Is this part of an ongoing contest, or has the contest ended?  2.  What have you tried?

Comment: @Gero Your profile says you are self-studying math olympiad problems. That's great! However, it would be really helpful if you could add references for such problems (especially ones which look like they are from 2015) because people here don't want to accidentally offer hints or answers to an ongoing contest problem.

Comment: No, it is a problem I found in a mexican book, but I couldn't remember the exact year (it was two thousand and something), that's why I wrote $2015.$ Well, I'm sorry but, I've never seen a problem like this before and I really have no idea what to do (I have done a few things but nothing smart)

Comment: Must the integers $(a,b,c)$ be different? If not, the triple $(2015,2015,2015)$ meets the maximum.

Comment: @ajotatxe No, sorry, they should be distinct (not necessarily pairwise distinct)

Comment: @Gero the problem is in the following link (in spanish), in page number $148$ (it is from $2002$ mexican mathematical olympiad): https://ommgto.files.wordpress.com/2009/06/compilacion.pdf

Comment: Thank you!, I didn't remember where I found it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x=(a,b,c) \in X$ be such that $s_x=\sigma$.  Without loss of generality, we assume $a<c$.  As $(2001,1,2002)\in X$, we have established that $\sigma\geq 4004$.

If $a<c<b$, then $a\mid b$ and $c\mid b$.  Therefore, $a\leq\frac{b}{3}$ and $c\leq\frac{b}{2}$.  That is, $$\sigma=a+b+c\leq \frac{b}{3}+\frac{b}{2}+b=\frac{11}{6}b<2b\leq2\cdot 2002=4004\,,$$ which is a contradiction.

If $a<b<c$, then $a\mid b\mid c$.  Therefore, $b\leq\frac{c}{2}$ and $a\leq \frac{b}{2}\leq \frac{c}{4}$.  Thus, $$\sigma=a+b+c\leq \frac{c}{4}+\frac{c}{2}+c=\frac{7}{4}c<2c\leq 2\cdot 2002=4004\,,$$ which is a contradiction.

If $b<a$, then $b\mid a$ and $b\mid c$.  Hence, $a\leq c-b$; i.e., $$\sigma=a+b+c\leq(c-b)+b+c=2c\leq 2\cdot 2002=4004\,.$$  Therefore, $\sigma=4004$, whence we must have $a=c-b > b$, $c=2002$, and $b\mid c$.  That is, $b$ is any divisor of $2002$ less than $\frac{2002}{2}=1001$, which are $1$, $2$, $7$, $11$, $13$, $14$, $22$, $26$, $77$, $91$, $143$, $154$, $182$, and $286$.

In summary, $\sigma=4004$, and $s_x=\sigma$ if and only if $x=(a,b,c)$ is one of the followings (up to permutation between $a$ and $c$): $(2001,1,2002)$, $(2000,2,2002)$, $(1995,7,2002)$, $(1991,11,2002)$, $(1989,13,2002)$, $(1988,14,2002)$, $(1980,22,2002)$, $(1976,26,2002)$, $(1925,77,2002)$, $(1911,91,2002)$, $(1859,143,2002)$, $(1848,154,2002)$, $(1820,182,2002)$, and $(1716,286,2002)$.

**P.S.** In your earlier version, you used $2015$ in place of $2002$, so I have decided to write a general solution.  If $X$ is defined to be the set of compatible triples whose entries are in $\{1,2,\ldots,N\}$ for some fixed $N\in\mathbb{N}$ with $N\geq 3$, then $\sigma=2N$, and, for $x=(a,b,c)\in X$, $s_x=\sigma$ if and only if $b<\frac{N}{2}$ is a divisor of $N$ and $\{a,c\}=\{N-b,N\}$.